# Access a method of a class imported into the present class from a method in an inner class of the present class

Tags: java, android

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            int x = Integer.parseInt((String)listOutput.getText());
            listOutput.setText(Integer.toString(x+1));
            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            t.setText("hello");
            //Intent openTabbedActivity = new Intent(this,New_tabbed_activity.cl);
        }
      });
```

I want to use `setText()`method of the `TextView` class or `Intent` constructor of the `Intent` class from inside the `onItemClick()` of the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` class inside the `MainActivity` class

But Android studio says
`cannot resolve method setText`
same is being shown for `Intent()` also

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            int x = Integer.parseInt((String)listOutput.getText());
            view.listOutput.setText(Integer.toString(x+1));
            TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            view.t.setText("hello");
            //Intent openTabbedActivity = new Intent(this,New_tabbed_activity.cl); 
        } 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

With some browsing through some examples I found that the problem was the `context`
In the intent the constructor's first parameter should be `MainActivity.this` not just `this`

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        int x = Integer.parseInt((String)listOutput.getText());
        listOutput.setText(Integer.toString(x+1));
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        MainActiviy.this.t.setText("hello");
        Intent openTabbedActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,New_tabbed_activity.cl);
    }
  });
```